# create dictionary with list items as keys and their number of occurance as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

and I want to make a dictionary like this:

```
result = {1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1}
# key is unique list items
# and value is the times they have been repeated in list
```

I could get this done by this piece of code but doesn't look good:

```
def parse_list(my_list):
    result = {}
    my_set = set(my_list)
    for i in my_set:
        result[i] = len([j for j in my_list if j == i])
    return result
```

I think this should be achievable with less loops.
Any idea?

Comment: Yes, if you can use libraries ..

Comment: yes. I can use libraries. but don't know what to use.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter Your ques has already got an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> Counter(my_list)
Counter({1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1})

>>> dict(Counter(my_list))
{1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 1}
```

Comment: @Taxellool: Note that `Counter` inherits from `dict` so you can use it just like a `dict`. So that final conversion step isn't really necessary, but I guess if you're making lots of these things a plain `dict` uses a little bit less memory than a `Counter`.